# How to pull only differences from git repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have 2 web servers with the same files except for maybe 4-5 files having changes. The server with the changes is already tied to a git repo on bitbucket.
How do i tie my second server to the same git repo and only make changes to the files with the differences (with all other files being the same[from the same webapp]).

Sorry for the elementary question, I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around git and how to do this without ruining either system.

Comment: This sounds like you might have some confusion about how Git works.  In Git, each _commit_ conceptually involves _every_ file in the repository.  So when you sync one computer with a Git repo, _every_ file gets pulled in.

Comment: Thanks for the response tim, will it overwrite files that are the same?

Comment: Git doesn't work this way.  Each sync will always replace _every_ file conceptually.  Git is not a file-based version control system.

Comment: So i would just have to clone to repo into the directory correct?